Unable to find the partition with the UUID mentioned in metadata in STM32MP1
We have developed a custom board based on an STM32MP157 chip. We also forked the tf-a and u-boot from the meta-st layer. If we flash an SD card using the flash layout, the image works. But my goal is to copy the files from the Linux host machine, which I did. Now the image does not boot from the SD card. It is showing the following error.
NOTICE: CPU: STM32MP157CAA Rev.Z
NOTICE: Model: emtrion DIMM-Argon stm32mp157c, yocto, SDCARD
INFO: Reset reason (0x15):
INFO: Power-on Reset (rst_por)
INFO: FCONF: Reading TB_FW firmware configuration file from: 0x2ffe2000
INFO: FCONF: Reading firmware configuration information for: stm32mp_io
INFO: Using EMMC
INFO: Instance 2
INFO: Boot used partition fsbl1
NOTICE: BL2: v2.6-stm32mp1-r2.0(debug):v2.6-dirty(a1f02f4f)
NOTICE: BL2: Built : 13:14:26, Nov 23 2021
ERROR: Unable to find the partition with the uuid mentioned in metadata

How can I solve this?
